# Can I use ImageMagick to determine the length of the X and Y axes?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I get an image back from an API, and depending on the parameters, sometimes it's in landscape mode and sometimes portrait.  I could hardcode a check of the parameter settings to determine what the mode is but I'd rather examine the image and figure it out.  The "Orientation" field returned by `identify` is "Undefined" - is there another way for me to figure out what the orientation is?

Comment: Er... are you using Imagick class, or the ole exec command line version?

Comment: The PHP class `Imagick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method returns just the `width` & `height` as an associative array: [getImageGeometry](https://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagegeometry.php)

An example to figure out landscape or portrait using Imagick image sizes:

```
$filename = '/path/to/image.jpg';
$image = new imagick($filename);
$size = $image->getImageGeometry();
$orientation = ( $size['width'] > $size['height'] ) ? 'landscape' : 'portrait';
echo $orientation;
```

If you have a 'square' image... it will be considered 'portrait'. You can adjust if it matters.